# Visual Studio Code not highlighting #if.. in C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

I try to get VS-Code working for my C++ project, but I have the problem that the syntax highlighting ignores preprocessor directives like `#if/#else/#endif`.

I have the extensions `ms-vscode.cpptools` (C/C++) and `ext install code-gnu-global` (Intellisense) installed.

"Go To Definition" shows the `#define` correctly.

[image]

`#define ON_TARGET false` results to the same highlighting

It should look like this:

[image]

Comment: In this rare case, a screenshot could be better than a textual description only.

Comment: Added a screenshot.

Comment: Do you want that the c++ code the block of the `#if` that does not macht the condition to be e.g. greyed out? Or what do you mean with `[...]results to the same highlighting[...]`

Comment: VSCode is not a compiler and it has no idea what your code *means*.

Comment: But why does it work then if I replace the variable with a "1" or a "0"? (see second picture)

Comment: Because `#define 0` is so clear that you don't need a compiler for that.

Comment: It can recognize `#if 0` or `#if 1`, but not more complex things like `#if somevariable` where `somevariable` is defined elsewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visual Studio Code can't do such things out of the box as it is "just" an **editor**.

If you compile your code, it will work as expected.

For evaluating such defines you need an **IDE**, e.g. Visual Studio, CLion or you may achieve this with additional **Plugins**. (e.g. [C/C++ Plugin](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.cpptools))

Comment: Ok, thanks. I thought VSCode is more than just a editor. So I can stick to Aton/Notepad++ or the "real" VS if I want an editor/IDE. Thought VSCode might be a lightweight IDE, misinterpreted that....

Comment: @thetemplar You can do more than just edit code with VSCode. You can set breakpoints, debug your code or execute defined tasks. And it can be used on Windows, macOS and Linux. Check this. [link](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/cpp)

Comment: Sorry, you are right. But I have to use a third party compiler and debugger and sadly can't use those tools, so I forgot about them and the use of it for other devs.

Comment: I think after some years, VSCode has evolved so much thanks to plugins and become like an IDE, to my point of view. 
Recently the lines between IDE's and Editors has become blurred.
This answer was maybe true when it was written, but it is not valid anymore.

Answer (score 4):

VS Code can do it with Microsoft's C/C++ extension since [v 0.15](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cpptools/blob/master/Extension/CHANGELOG.md#version-0150-february-15-2018)
 from February 2018.

[image]

Comment: I accidentally diactivated it. How should I activate it again?

Comment: Go to settings File / Preferences / Settings or ctrl + , and in the `search settings` field, type `dim inactive regions` and you will see the option to enable and disable it

Comment: @JoelSantosRico worked so thanks! but how would I just define the missing variable?

Comment: Not sure about what you mean. You have two sources for your defines, the ones that you explicitly add in your code (in my screenshot, the `#define HAL_CONFIG`). If it's in the same file, VS Code will pick it up. If it's not on the same file (another header, for example, that you '#include`) then you have to make sure that your `c_cpp_settings.json` has the path to the folder containing it in the `includePath`. I'll continue in the next comment

Comment: Alternatively, some macros are defined at compilation time, in the command line. What I do is trigger a compilation (with your IDE, or `make`, or whatever you do) and capture the full compilation command. How those macros are defined might change from compiler to compiler, but in GCC they take the form `-DNAME=VALUE` which is equivalent to having a line that says `#define NAME VALUE` in your code. You can add all those compilation time defines in the `c_cpp_properties.json` too, in the `defines` key. 
Check this https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/c-cpp-properties-schema-reference